# Bootstrap submit form in modal and stay in same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, bootstrap-modal

Im using **bootstrap** in my **grails** project,in one of my **gsp** pages I have a **button(b1)** that when I click it a bootstrap modal is shown.In the modal I have a form and submit button,what I need is to exit the modal after submitting the form and stay in the same page that I was (the page that contains **b1**)

This is my code :

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">${'Volunteer for ' + tekEventInstance.name}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <label class="label-warning">Welcome to the team!
                Your help will make a huge difference.</label>
                <g:form controller="tekEvent" action="volunteer" method="POST" target="_blank">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${tekEventInstance.id}" />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
                </g:form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

My **volunteer** action renders a message after the form is submitted.I was using **gui:dialog** before bootstrap and the message was shown in same page but now its shown in a new window with url:`http://localhost:8080/TekDays/tekEvent/volunteer` .I don't even have a page with volunteer.gsp !!!

This is my volunteer action:

```
def volunteer = {
    def event = TekEvent.get(params.id)
    event.addToVolunteers(session.user)
    event.save()
    render "Thank you for Volunteering"

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by following ways:

Use ajax to submit the values to the action. Please refer to this link.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Or

Create formRemote. 
http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/ref/Tags/formRemote.html

Or

Redirect from volunteer action to the action where your above mentioned gsp is rendered.

Thanks

Comment: I tried using formRemote and it calls the action correctly and the message is shown in the backgroung page but the problem is that the modal is not closed . 
In the 3rd aproach how can I send a message then?
I'll update my question and add my controller to it